# Which is right "office hours" or "office hour"?

Tags: american-english

I want to ask a person what time should I start to work.

What is the regular office hour?

OR

What are the regular office hours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the period of work in question is a specific single hour (unlikely), the correct version is your second one.

Alternatives might be:

> What are your business hours?
>   What are your opening and closing times?
>   (If it's a retail business)
>   What hours am I expected to work?

Comment: I'd issue a word of caution to the learner. Business hours might be from 8AM to 6PM, but the workers might be expected to arrive at 7:30. "Business hours" and "work hours" aren't necessarily the same, which is why I like your last version best, in regards to the O.P.'s question.

Answer (score 1):

In academia, an *office hour* is an appointed time when a professor is available to meet with students who might have questions.

To avoid confusion, you might want to use a different expression, like one of these:

- What are the reporting hours?
- What times am I expected to work?
- When does my working day start and end?

Note: Those questions are designed to give both a start time and an end time for your work day. If you are primarily interested in what time you start your work day, you can use one of these:

- What time am I expected to show up?
- How early do I need to be here?